# Is there a way to open multiple ed2k links for amule/emule?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firefox-extensions, emule

For example, if I copy just one ed2k link on firefox address bar

```
 ed2k://|file|firemule-0.4.1-fx.[contentdb.emule-project.net].zip|15754|7F35BB7A70E9BF16F81D10AFC6DF5079|h=Y4KHCMOFRCVFJGKTN7DBZD7SVE5EEABU|/
```

I have not problem: a window appears, ask me to open with emule/Amule and work is done

But I have many ed2k links that I want to

```
ed2k://|file|firem....
ed2k://|file|firem....
ed2k://|file|firem....
ed2k://|file|firem....
...
```

I try to use firefox extension "open multiple urls" but doesn't work.
Is there a workaround to open a list of ed2k links?

Comment: Is the issue that the app cannot handle multiple simultaneous links? What emule app are you using

Comment: I use Amule (emule for ubuntu)